# Несколько name в одном input

Tags: php, html, css

Всем привет.
Подскажите, как в одном input я могу задать 2 значения name?

Пытаюсь сделать так, но ничего не выходит, не работает

`<input type="text" placeholder="Телефон" name="phone" name="entry.1312741979">`

Значения поля `name="phone"` я затем получаю через $_POST и записываю в БД.

Значения поля `name="entry.1312741979"` я записываю в гугл таблицу.

По отдельности `name="entry.1312741979"` и `name="phone"` работает, как только я прописываю так `<input type="text" placeholder="Телефон" name="phone" name="entry.1312741979">` выполняется только первое действие, запись в бд, в гугл таблицу не записывает

Спасибо

Comment: не можете. Каков смысл этого действа?

Comment: Смысл в том, что бы отправлять данные в гугл таблицу и параллельно записывать в бд. Запись в гугл таблицу осуществляется через `entry.1312741979` а запись в бд через `phone`. И мне нужно 2 атрибута name, так как я не могу задать `$_POST['entry.1312741979']`

Comment: Нашла выход на просторах интернета "если в форме создать поле Input с именем Name содержащем точку, то браузер автоматически подменяет её на нижнее подчеркивание!"

Comment: почему не создать словарик, где ключами будут первые имена, а значениями соответствующие им вторые имена? `phone -> entry.1312741979`

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [спецификации HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2), вы не можете иметь два абсолютно одинаковых атрибута в одном теге. Точнее можете, но поведение будет **неопределенное**, браузер будет вероятно разбирать только первое значение, а второе игнорировать.

> There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose
>   names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other.

Для того, чтобы отправлять данные в сторонний сервис с разным форматом имен:

**1)** Можно использовать специальные атрибуты data-*, которые позволят Вам через Javascript их обрабатывать и отправлять на сервер. Создаете например атрибут data-name, сначала отправляете свою форму в базу данных через Ajax, а потом немного Javascript, получаете все input'ы с data-name и отправляете их второй формой, так же через Ajax.

**2)** На стороне сервера использовать заготовленный Mapper, который будет преобразовывать названия имен, типа phone в entry.1312741979 и отправлять далее в сервис по API.

Answer (score 0):

У элемента **input** не может быть 2 атрибута **name**. Посмотрите [тут](https://webref.ru/html/input) все допустимые атрибуты.

В вашем случае наиболее уместным решением будет создание дублирующих инпутов **type="hidden"** и немного **jquery**:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Телефон" name="phone" />
<input type="hidden" placeholder="Телефон" name="entry.1312741979" />
```